# Python Pandas: How to extract particular row based on other column rows in a txt file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Consider the following Dataframe

```
A='pickle.loads(b\'\\x80\\x03cpandas.core.frame\\nDataFrame\\nq\\x00)\\x81q\\x01}q\\x02(X\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00_dataq\\x03cpandas.core.internals\\nBlockManager\\nq\\x04)\\x81q\\x05(]q\\x06(cpandas.core.indexes.base\\n_new_Index\\nq\\x07cpandas.core.indexes.base\\nIndex\\nq\\x08}q\\t(X\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00dataq\\ncnumpy.core.multiarray\\n_reconstruct\\nq\\x0bcnumpy\\nndarray\\nq\\x0cK\\x00\\x85q\\rC\\x01bq\\x0e\\x87q\\x0fRq\\x10(K\\x01K\\x04\\x85q\\x11cnumpy\\ndtype\\nq\\x12X\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00O8q\\x13K\\x00K\\x01\\x87q\\x14Rq\\x15(K\\x03X\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00|q\\x16NNNJ\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xffJ\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xffK?tq\\x17b\\x89]q\\x18(X\\x07\\x00\\x00\\x00Invoiceq\\x19X\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00Itemsq\\x1aX\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00Priceq\\x1bX\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00Totalq\\x1cetq\\x1dbX\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00nameq\\x1eNu\\x86q\\x1fRq h\\x07cpandas.core.indexes.range\\nRangeIndex\\nq!}q"(h\\x1eNX\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00startq#K\\x00X\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00stopq$K\\x05X\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00stepq%K\\x01u\\x86q&Rq\\\'e]q((h\\x0bh\\x0cK\\x00\\x85q)h\\x0e\\x87q*Rq+(K\\x01K\\x03K\\x05\\x86q,h\\x12X\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00f8q-K\\x00K\\x01\\x87q.Rq/(K\\x03X\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00<q0NNNJ\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xffJ\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xffK\\x00tq1b\\x89Cx\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x80\\xdd\\xc5@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x80\\xdd\\xc5@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x80\\xdd\\xc5@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xde\\xc5@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x80\\xde\\xc5@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00p\\xa7@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x94\\xc1@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00@\\x8f@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00@\\x8f@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00L\\xcd@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00d\\xc9@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00d\\xc9@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00d\\xc9@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00@\\x8f@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00L\\xcd@q2tq3bh\\x0bh\\x0cK\\x00\\x85q4h\\x0e\\x87q5Rq6(K\\x01K\\x01K\\x05\\x86q7h\\x15\\x89]q8(X\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00Item_1q9X\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00Item_2q:X\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00Item_3q;X\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00Item_4q<X\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00Item_5q=etq>be]q?(h\\x07h\\x08}q@(h\\nh\\x0bh\\x0cK\\x00\\x85qAh\\x0e\\x87qBRqC(K\\x01K\\x03\\x85qDh\\x15\\x89]qE(h\\x19h\\x1bh\\x1cetqFbh\\x1eNu\\x86qGRqHh\\x07h\\x08}qI(h\\nh\\x0bh\\x0cK\\x00\\x85qJh\\x0e\\x87qKRqL(K\\x01K\\x01\\x85qMh\\x15\\x89]qNh\\x1aatqObh\\x1eNu\\x86qPRqQe}qRX\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x000.14.1qS}qT(X\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00axesqUh\\x06X\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00blocksqV]qW(}qX(X\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00valuesqYh+X\\x08\\x00\\x00\\x00mgr_locsqZh\\x0bh\\x0cK\\x00\\x85q[h\\x0e\\x87q\\\\Rq](K\\x01K\\x03\\x85q^h\\x12X\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00i8q_K\\x00K\\x01\\x87q`Rqa(K\\x03h0NNNJ\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xffJ\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xffK\\x00tqbb\\x89C\\x18\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00qctqdbu}qe(hYh6hZcbuiltins\\nslice\\nqfK\\x01K\\x02K\\x01\\x87qgRqhueustqibX\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00_typqjX\\t\\x00\\x00\\x00dataframeqkX\\t\\x00\\x00\\x00_metadataql]qmub.\')'

import pickle
df=eval(A)
```

That is

[image]

I want to extract these items on line bases depending on the value of invoice i.e. In the example here

I want to have a text file as follow

```
Item_1, Item_2, Item_3
Item_4 
Item_5
```

[image: enter i,mage description here]
Obviously there might be some lines where we have the same Item twice or more

For example, one line could be as

```
Item_1, Item_2, Item_75, Item_2, Item_85
```

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `join` and write to file [`Series.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html) with separator different as joined value for avoid `""`:

```
df.groupby('Invoice')['Items'].apply(', '.join).to_csv('file.csv', index=False, sep=';')
```

Comment: @rsc05 - Glad can help!